# RadComboBox: select item programmatically in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, browser

I'm using Webbrowser to automate website actions. Combobox in my case on the website is a RasComboBox. 
I know that there are two options to select item

1) Find appropriate INPUT element and set its value to desired item text.
2) Click down arrow button, wait until dropdown populated and then select desired item.

I used 1st option. And it inserted desired item's value successfully, dropdown was shown and populated with my item selected.

But how to close dropdown then? Can't find proper action to do it.. Please help.

Here is how I put text into RadComboBox:

```
    HtmlElement elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("step1SP_dgGroups_ctl02_ucSG_dgSG_ctl00_rcbFilterType_Input");
            elem.InnerText = "Orders";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SetAttribute` method for that:

```
HtmlElement elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("step1SP_dgGroups_ctl02_ucSG_dgSG_ctl00_rcbFilterType_Input");
elem.SetAttribute("value", "Orders");
```